# Preview window of RENDERMAN

Tags: materials

This is a question about indication of material setting in "RENDERMAN for Blender". Display of the preview window changed as shown in the following image. What is this cause? I want to return this display to the original (left side).
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you detail a bit what happened in between?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause. It is a set of sampling in Render Propaty. I'm sorry for upsetting you.

[image]
[image]